Computing Centralizers of Specific Direct Product Groups in Symmetric Groups
Let $ G \leq S_n $ be a subgroup of the symmetric group $ S_n $. The centralizer of $ G $ in $ S_n $ is defined as:
$$
C_{S_n}(G) = \{ \sigma \in S_n : \sigma g = g \sigma \text{ for all } g \in G \}.
$$
I am interested in computing the following centralizers for specific subgroups of $ S_{n \cdot k} $:

$ C_{S_{n \cdot k}}(C_n \times C_k) $, where $ C_n \times C_k $ denotes the direct product of two cyclic groups of order $ n $ and $ k $, respectively.
$ C_{S_{n \cdot k}}(S_n \times S_k) $, where $ S_n \times S_k $ denotes the direct product of two symmetric groups.

To clarify the action of $ C_n \times C_k $ on a matrix $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k} $, the element $ (g_1, g_2) \in C_n \times C_k $ acts as follows:
$$
A \mapsto P_{g_1} A P_{g_2},
$$
where $ P_{g_1} $ and $ P_{g_2} $ are permutation matrices corresponding to $ g_1 $ and $ g_2 $, respectively.
In vectorized form, this action becomes:
$$
\operatorname{vec}(A) \mapsto (P_{g_2}^T \otimes P_{g_1}) \operatorname{vec}(A),
$$
using the vectorization identity $ \operatorname{vec}(ABC) = (C^T \otimes A) \operatorname{vec}(B) $.
Similarly, for the group $ S_n \times S_k $, an element $ (g_1, g_2) \in S_n \times S_k $ acts on $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k} $ in the same way:
$$
A \mapsto P_{g_1} A P_{g_2},
$$
where $ P_{g_1} $ and $ P_{g_2} $ are now permutation matrices corresponding to elements of $ S_n $ and $ S_k $.
In vectorized form, the action is:
$$
\operatorname{vec}(A) \mapsto (P_{g_2}^T \otimes P_{g_1}) \operatorname{vec}(A).
$$
Question: Is there a known method or result for finding the centralizers:
$$
C_{S_{n \cdot k}}(C_n \times C_k)
$$
and
$$
C_{S_{n \cdot k}}(S_n \times S_k)?
$$

Might it be better to work over $\mathbb{C}$, and compute the centralizer in $$End_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}^{nk})\supset GL(nk,\mathbb{C})\supset S_{nk} $$ This allows a good deal of representation theory to be leveraged.
